# Weird tick border line when i click the mobile-menu-toggle Bootstrap5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

[image]

The weird outline is showed up when i click the mobile nav menu bar. It does not show up when i tested with Safari. It only shows up in Chrome Browser...

I do not know why..

Comment: Please add the HTML and CSS that relates to the button so we can better help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is showing box-shadow by default if you want to remove it i am providing a css code below:

```
.navbar-toggler:focus{
    box-shadow: none !important;
 }
```